# Which version of protocol buffers does TensorFlow 1.1 depend on?

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers

It is unclear which version of protocol buffers TensorFlow 1.1 depends on.

- The pip package built by TensorFlow 1.1 [depends on protobuf >= 3.2](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/setup.py#L37).
- The [TensorFlow installation instructions for Ubuntu](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#protobuf_pip_package_31) reference protobuf 3.1.

Furthermore, attempting to build TensorFlow 1.1 from source whilst using protobuf 3.1, 3.2, or 3.3 built from source fails.

I can build TensorFlow 1.1 from source as long as I allow it to build its own copy of protobuf but I would rather it used a common version if possible.

If I build protobuf 3.1 from source and then attempt to build TensorFlow 1.1 from source I get the following error:

```
ERROR: <snip>/.cache/bazel/_bazel_daniel/041a78b467f26d47aee0fcd68c1f3624/external/protobuf/BUILD:73:1: C++ compilation of rule '@protobuf//:protobuf_lite' failed: gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -B/usr/bin -B/usr/bin -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG ... (remaining 45 argument(s) skipped): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc:393:67: error: no 'void google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteFloatArray(const float*, int, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)' member function declared in class 'google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite'
                                      io::CodedOutputStream* output) {
                                                                   ^
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc:398:67: error: no 'void google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteDoubleArray(const double*, int, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)' member function declared in class 'google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite'
                                      io::CodedOutputStream* output) {
                                                                   ^
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc:403:67: error: no 'void google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteFixed32Array(const uint32*, int, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)' member function declared in class 'google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite'
                                      io::CodedOutputStream* output) {
                                                                   ^
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc:408:69: error: no 'void google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteFixed64Array(const uint64*, int, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)' member function declared in class 'google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite'
                                        io::CodedOutputStream* output) {
                                                                     ^
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc:413:69: error: no 'void google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteSFixed32Array(const int32*, int, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)' member function declared in class 'google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite'
                                        io::CodedOutputStream* output) {
                                                                     ^
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc:418:69: error: no 'void google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteSFixed64Array(const int64*, int, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)' member function declared in class 'google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite'
                                        io::CodedOutputStream* output) {
                                                                     ^
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc:423:66: error: no 'void google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteBoolArray(const bool*, int, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)' member function declared in class 'google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite'
                                     io::CodedOutputStream* output) {
                                                                  ^
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc: In static member function 'static void google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteGroupMaybeToArray(int, const google::protobuf::MessageLite&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)':
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc:557:17: error: 'class google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream' has no member named 'IsSerializationDeterministic'
         output->IsSerializationDeterministic(), target);
                 ^
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc: In static member function 'static void google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteMessageMaybeToArray(int, const google::protobuf::MessageLite&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)':
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc:574:17: error: 'class google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream' has no member named 'IsSerializationDeterministic'
         output->IsSerializationDeterministic(), target);
                 ^
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc: At global scope:
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc:739:8: error: prototype for 'size_t google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::Int32Size(const google::protobuf::RepeatedField<int>&)' does not match any in class 'google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite'
 size_t WireFormatLite::Int32Size(const RepeatedField<int32>& value) {
        ^
In file included from external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc:35:0:
<snip>/source/protobuf/protobuf-3.1.0/inst/include/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite_inl.h:813:15: error: candidate is: static size_t google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::Int32Size(google::protobuf::int32)
 inline size_t WireFormatLite::Int32Size(int32 value) {
               ^
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc:748:8: error: prototype for 'size_t google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::UInt32Size(const google::protobuf::RepeatedField<unsigned int>&)' does not match any in class 'google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite'
 size_t WireFormatLite::UInt32Size(const RepeatedField<uint32>& value) {
        ^
In file included from external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc:35:0:
<snip>/source/protobuf/protobuf-3.1.0/inst/include/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite_inl.h:819:15: error: candidate is: static size_t google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::UInt32Size(google::protobuf::uint32)
 inline size_t WireFormatLite::UInt32Size(uint32 value) {
               ^
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc:757:8: error: prototype for 'size_t google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::SInt32Size(const google::protobuf::RepeatedField<int>&)' does not match any in class 'google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite'
 size_t WireFormatLite::SInt32Size(const RepeatedField<int32>& value) {
        ^
In file included from external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc:35:0:
<snip>/source/protobuf/protobuf-3.1.0/inst/include/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite_inl.h:825:15: error: candidate is: static size_t google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::SInt32Size(google::protobuf::int32)
 inline size_t WireFormatLite::SInt32Size(int32 value) {
               ^
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc:766:8: error: prototype for 'size_t google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::EnumSize(const google::protobuf::RepeatedField<int>&)' does not match any in class 'google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite'
 size_t WireFormatLite::EnumSize(const RepeatedField<int>& value) {
        ^
In file included from external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc:35:0:
<snip>/source/protobuf/protobuf-3.1.0/inst/include/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite_inl.h:831:15: error: candidate is: static size_t google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::EnumSize(int)
 inline size_t WireFormatLite::EnumSize(int value) {
               ^
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
```

If I build protobuf 3.2 from source and then attempt to build TensorFlow 1.1 from source I get the following error:

```
ERROR: <snip>/.cache/bazel/_bazel_daniel/041a78b467f26d47aee0fcd68c1f3624/external/protobuf/BUILD:113:1: C++ compilation of rule '@protobuf//:protobuf' failed: gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -B/usr/bin -B/usr/bin -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG ... (remaining 43 argument(s) skipped): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/util/json_util.cc:52:49: error: definition of implicitly-declared 'virtual google::protobuf::util::internal::ZeroCopyStreamByteSink::~ZeroCopyStreamByteSink()'
 ZeroCopyStreamByteSink::~ZeroCopyStreamByteSink() {
                                                 ^
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/util/json_util.cc: In member function 'virtual void google::protobuf::util::internal::ZeroCopyStreamByteSink::Append(const char*, size_t)':
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/util/json_util.cc:58:16: error: 'buffer_size_' was not declared in this scope
     if (len <= buffer_size_) {
                ^
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/util/json_util.cc:59:14: error: 'buffer_' was not declared in this scope
       memcpy(buffer_, bytes, len);
              ^
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/util/json_util.cc:64:12: error: 'buffer_' was not declared in this scope
     memcpy(buffer_, bytes, buffer_size_);
            ^
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/util/json_util.cc:64:28: error: 'buffer_size_' was not declared in this scope
     memcpy(buffer_, bytes, buffer_size_);
                            ^
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/util/json_util.cc: In function 'google::protobuf::util::Status google::protobuf::util::BinaryToJsonStream(google::protobuf::util::TypeResolver*, const string&, google::protobuf::io::ZeroCopyInputStream*, google::protobuf::io::ZeroCopyOutputStream*, const google::protobuf::util::JsonPrintOptions&)':
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/util/json_util.cc:85:47: error: 'const struct google::protobuf::util::JsonPrintOptions' has no member named 'always_print_enums_as_ints'
   proto_source.set_use_ints_for_enums(options.always_print_enums_as_ints);
                                               ^
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
```

If I build protobuf 3.3 from source and then attempt to build TensorFlow 1.1 from source I get the following error:

```
ERROR: <snip>/.cache/bazel/_bazel_daniel/041a78b467f26d47aee0fcd68c1f3624/external/protobuf/BUILD:73:1: C++ compilation of rule '@protobuf//:protobuf_lite' failed: gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -B/usr/bin -B/usr/bin -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG ... (remaining 45 argument(s) skipped): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/arenastring.cc:41:6: error: redefinition of 'void google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::AssignWithDefault(const string*, google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr)'
 void ArenaStringPtr::AssignWithDefault(const ::std::string* default_value,
      ^
In file included from external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/arenastring.cc:34:0:
<snip>/source/protobuf/protobuf-3.3.0/inst/include/google/protobuf/arenastring.h:316:13: note: 'void google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::AssignWithDefault(const string*, google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr)' previously defined here
 inline void ArenaStringPtr::AssignWithDefault(const ::std::string* default_value,
             ^
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
```

Comment: Seems that you build tensorflow with bazel? Did you configure the protobuf version in the tensorflow/workspace.bzl?

Comment: @samuel Thanks, and yes, I'm compiling with Bazel and no, I didn't configure the protobuf version in the workspace.bzl. I can't find anything in the default workspace file for configuring protobuf compilation/linking and I've not yet found any documentation on how to add it. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: In my case, tensorflow 1.0.0, protobuf is configured in $tensorflow_install/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl. native.http_archive(
      name = "protobuf",
      urls = [
          "http://bazel-mirror.storage.googleapis.com/github.com/google/protobuf/archive/008b5a228b37c054f46ba478ccafa5e855cb16db.tar.gz",
          "https://github.com/google/protobuf/archive/008b5a228b37c054f46ba478ccafa5e855cb16db.tar.gz",
      ],
      sha256 = "2737ad055eb8a9bc63ed068e32c4ea280b62d8236578cb4d4120eb5543f759ab",
      strip_prefix = "protobuf-008b5a228b37c054f46ba478ccafa5e855cb16db",

Comment: Ah, I see the `.bzl` file is modified by the build and while the original Github version contains the protobuf bits, my modified version does not. Looks like the next version of TensorFlow (1.3?) will depend on at least protobuf 3.3.1. I suspect my problem is actually caused by building protobuf without Bazel and then building TensorFlow with Bazel.